# JQuery aplicar a mesma função em uma div duplicada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia, estou aprendendo a programar em JS e JQuery e me deparei com um problema que ainda não consegui resolver. Usando PHP estou colocando dentro de um laço **While** uma tag **DIV** e uma tag **SPAN**, e dentro da span um **valor trazido do banco de dados**, desse jeito:

```
 while ($row_ano = $ne->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

     
    ?>
   
       <div class='n1 badge bg-primary text-wrap' 
     style='margin-left: 200px; width: 2rem; height: 2rem; border-radius: 50%;' id='nota'>    
        <span class='mt-1' id='text' value='nota'>
            <?php echo  $row_ano['nota'] ?>  
        </span> 
     </div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Nesse laço, ele repete essa div duas vezes, e com dois valores diferentes, somente dois valores. Eu planejava fazer com que o JQuery pegasse o valor dentro do **Span** e caso fosse menor que 6 a **div** ficasse *vermelha*, caso maior *azul* (*essa div, no caso, é um circulo*). Com isso, eu fiz isso:

```
    var color = $.each($("#text"), function() {  //o text é o id do span
    var nota = $("#nota").text(color);           //o nota é o id da div
    console.log(color);

    for (color=0;color < 6;color++){
        $("#nota").removeClass("badge bg-primary text-wrap");
        $("#nota").addClass("badge bg-danger text-wrap");
    } 
        color++;
    });
```

O meu problema é: Que se eu colocar dois valores menores que 6, somente **uma das div fica vermelha**, enquanto a outra continua **azul**, ou seja, esse trecho de código só está modificando somente uma div, enquanto ele deveria modificar as duas caso o valor fosse um número inferior a 6. Se alguém puder me ajudar a melhorar meu código ou a encontrar uma solução vou ficar muito grato.

*espero que alguém consiga entender o codigo, deve tá todo errado, tentei várias vezes resolver isso* :(

Comment: O id deve ser único no html. Outro ponto, por que usar o javascript para adicionar as classes? Por que não faz diretamente quando está gerando o html no php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro erro que está acontecendo, você não pode ter mais de um ID com o mesmo nome, quando precisamos ter mais de um seletor com o mesmo nome, usamos as classes.

Para acessar a tag pai, utilizamos a função `parent` e nela, adicionamos a classes necessária.

Eu acabei removendo o atributo style, pois não devemos adicionar estilização direto na tag, é recomendado criar uma classe para essa estilização.

```
<div class='n1 badge bg-primary text-wrap'>    
    <span class='mt-1 valor-nota'>
        <?php echo  $row_ano['nota'] ?>  
    </span> 
</div>



$.each($(".valor-nota"), function() {
    var valorNota = $(this).html()

    if(valorNota < 6){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('bg-primary').addClass('bg-danger')
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('bg-danger').addClass('bg-primary')
    }
});
```

Comment: me ajudou muito a resolver o meu problema e aprender mais um pouco, muito obrigado por disponibilizar seu tempo para ajudar.